# Oreo app install silently by system app signed with firmware key

Tags: android

I want to install other app by download and then install that app from my installed as a system app on oreo, I have installed using

```
 am.installPackage(PATH + "app.apk");
```

but through this, it is asking for install permission and installed action. Can some one help he to installed other app silently on oreo version. do i need to sign other APK with same sign key, so it wont ask any prompt for install / uninstall

Comment: and why do you even want to do that? Why install app without notifying user? Bloatware? Spyware?

Comment: It is for my embedded system i will install and update other app using it.

Comment: I wouldn't just because its either against or pushing too close to Google's terms if you use the Play Store for distribution https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/04/google-bans-self-updating-android-apps-possibly-including-facebooks/ I personally think it would be better to just make it known to users they can download another app for the play store in addition to and it provides this further enhancement and the apps work together. Otherwise, don't make two apps because its working too much as one.